# How to get data from firestore with react

Tags: reactjs

I've been at this for sooo long, (probably because i'm newish to react). I feel like it's easier but for some reason I cant't get it.

My intentions are to get data from Firestore and make a table with it in react.

I'm struggling to even get it to render to the page, I've tried heaps of different ways, following heaps of youtube vids, and reading up and can't seem to get it working, where am I going wrong. Can someone please help with this.

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MealPlanComponent from "../component/mealPlanComponent";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { Homepage } from "../pages/homepage";
import { AuthProvider } from "./authContext";
import { Form } from "react-router-dom";

export function CreateUserDatabase() {
  const [mealData, setMealData] = useState([]);

  const mealCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(mealCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      setMealData(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            viewing: false,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
        })
      );
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {mealData.map((meal, i) => (
        <div key={meal.id}>
          <h3>{meal.meals}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the getDoc method.
You could reference the below code picked up from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en&authuser=1#web-version-9_1)

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```